# Excel-VBA Compatibility Issue

Tags: vba, charts, excel-2007, compatibility, excel-2010

I have used following statement in my Excel Dashboard:

```
HeaderTableSheet.ChartObjects("Header_BreakEvenAnalysis").Copy
```

It works fine everytime on Excel-2007 but gives error **"Application-defined or Object-defined Error"** in Excel-2010 (That too not everytime)

I am not able to figure out the reason as well.

Any solution/work-around for the same please?

Comment: Have you noticed that 2007 was a troulbe maker between 2003 and 2010.. That to say, going towards 2007, the object model changed and infact it missed out quite some (specially in Charting object class). So are using a `macro` here?

Comment: @bonCodigo: Yes I am using a macro here. Any workaround you can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The sheet needs to be activated before copying the chart (This is required in Excel-2010 only)

So the following code worked:

```
HeaderTableSheet.Activate
HeaderTableSheet.ChartObjects("Header_BreakEvenAnalysis").Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub yourSUB()
Dim myChart As ChartObject

'--- other codes

    For Each myChart In Sheets("SheetName").ChartObjects
      If myChart.Name = "Header_BreakEvenAnalysis" Then
        myChart.Copy 
      End If
    Next myChart

'---other codes
'---release the memory and clean up
Set myChart = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this immediately after reaching home.

Comment: Thank you for the try but it didn't work. I have posted the solution I found as answer here.